# Unable to fully log out - RailsTutorial.org - Chapter 8

Tags: ruby-on-rails, railstutorial.org

I'm working through the tutorial at Railstutorial.org and have completed chapter 8 with passing tests. My issue is that if I follow the guide's code exactly, I am able to log in, but **unable** to **log out**.

If I click "Log out" I am redirected to the root_path, but as a still logged in member.

I think I traced the behavior to my sessions helper. Specifically the following lines:

```
  def current_user
    @current_user ||= User.find_by_remember_token(cookies[:remember_token])
  end
```

Through the rails console and pry I was able to determine that cookies[:remember_token] is nil, but since my user's remember_token is also nil, the find_by_remember_token is saying, "Hey nil == nil! Great! We found our user!" Except that this is obviously not desired behavior.

I've fixed it by changing the current_user method to the following:

```
  def current_user
   @current_user ||= cookies[:remember_token] && User.find_by_remember_token(cookies[:remember_token])
  end
```

I completely accept and understand that this is likely an error in my code. I've found Michael Hartl's commit from this point in the project and compared our files and can't find a discrepancy. Any ideas on what might be going on here?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score -1):

put this in your...

Controller:

```
def logout
   reset_session
   redirect_to :controller => 'classified', :action => 'list'
end
```

and in your view: you need to add a logout link.

```
<% else %>
    <p><%= "Welcome #{session[:user].login}!" -%></p>
    <p><%= link_to 'Logout', :controller => 'user',:action => 'logout' -%></p>
<% end %>
```